# Do I need to enable HSTS in addition to forcing HTTPS in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, hsts

I know nothing about this stuff so please ELI5 in your replies.

Following the instructions from my provider, Dreamhost, I installed an SSL certificate and then added these lines to my .htaccess file to force HTTP requests to be rewritten to HTTPS requests.

```
# Redirect http requests to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Everything seems to be working correctly, ie: every time I try to access a page under that domain with HTTP, it is rewritten to HTTPS and the "Secure" icon shows in the address bar.

My question is, do I need to also enable HSTS? Reading about it, it seems to do the exact same thing as the previous changes to the .htaccess file. Here's [an excerpt from A2 Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/security/ssl/enabling-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-for-your-site) (not my provider):

> Enabling HSTS
>
> When HSTS is enabled for a site, web browsers automatically change any
>   insecure requests (http://) to secure requests (https://). All you
>   need to do to enable HSTS is add a header to your site's .htaccess
>   file. Web browsers recognize this header, and then take care of the
>   rest without any further intervention on your part.

They suggest adding this to .htaccess:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

[Another tutorial](https://annevankesteren.nl/2016/02/dreamhost-https), this time specific to Dreamhost, says to enable HSTS along with forcing HTTPS in the .htaccess file, but doesn't really say why. This page suggests something slightly different:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31415926; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

Do I need the "https rewrite" code snippet AND HSTS? Or is having only the "https rewrite" code snippet good enough? Do I need the HSTS code at all, and if so, what's the difference between the two lines of HSTS code in my post?

Answer (score 8):

HSTS lets the browser know to only connect over `https` by default but each one of the different flags does something a bit different:

- includeSubdomains

That means that if your site is on `mydomain.com`, the policy will apply to all subdomains (i.e. `foo.mydomain.com`, `bar.mydomain.com`, etc). Without this included. the policy only applies for the exact domain in question.

- preload

While HSTS is great conceptually, the first time someone types `mydomain.com` the browser will try to contact your site on `http` scheme since it doesn't know that you have your site on `https` which gives a MITM attacker room to serve you malicious version of the site (aka [TOFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) problem).
To work around this, there is a centralized list for browsers for sites that should be contacted on `https` by default but to be able to get yourself on that list, you have to have the `preload` flag in that header. You can see more about this [here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hsts-preloading/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the two HSTS lines of code. However, I think maybe my question wasn't clear when I asked if I need "both". What I meant by "both" was, do I need the redirect snippet (at the top of my question) AND the HSTS code? Or should I choose just one, and if so, which one and why?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Do both. HSTS without the redirect is useless and the redirect without HSTS can be intercepted by a Man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: HSTS without the redirect works fine IF AND ONLY IF the user is using a modern browser that supports HSTS preloading.

Comment: This [SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices) seems applicable.

Answer (score 7):

The default, if a scheme (http or https) is not explicitly specified, is http.

Therefore a redirect is necessary to redirect it to your preferred https version since most visitors who type the URL will not include the scheme and so go to http version.

HTTP Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS) is a security method, to ensure you always **stay** on https. It is not really intended to do away with the need for the redirect. In particular HSTS works by sending your web browser a message (using a HTTP response header) to say "please only use https for this site, for the next X amount of time". This message should only be sent when visiting the site over https. Therefore if you do not redirect in the first place, then a lot of visitors may not even realise you have a https site and so will not get the HSTS instruction.

HSTS is mostly used as a way to change the default of a website to https, and to prevent man in the middle (MITM) attacks which might attempt to keep you on http: e.g. if you connect to a hacker's wifi network and go to your bank website, they will not be able to hijack this connection if it's done over https but will be able to if it's done over http, so attackers will intercept the http request and stop the redirect happening, to keep you on http and intercept all messages to and from your bank.

You can "preload" the HSTS instruction in web browser's code, which gives even more security, as you don't need to visit the site over https first to get the HSTS instruction. This should be caveated that there is basically no way back from this and this should only be considered if you really understand HSTS. There are [many, many, many requests to remove sites from Preload list](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527947) which takes a minimum of 3 months for Chrome (no guarantees for other browsers) and makes your site completely inaccessible during that time if you are not on https. So there is a real danger here! Particularly if some of your site is served over https (e.g. www.example.com) but some of it is not (e.g. intranet.example.com). This is a danger of HSTS as well but even more dangerous with preloading.

The other point to note is that many web agents will not use HSTS and especially not preload lists (e.g. Search Engine Crawlers, older browsers... etc). So again HSTS should be used on top of, instead of as a replacement to, a redirect.

HSTS is a great security measure and should be used by all sites (once they have stopped using http completely) but, like most security measures, does come with its own risks. So make sure you understand it before deploying it. I hate sites and tutorials that say turn it on without explaining it and the risks. In theory a site using HSTS may no longer need to redirect, but in practice it still will need to for the first visit and agents that don't understand or implement HSTS.

To summarise:

- Always use redirects.
- Strongly consider HSTS, but read up on it first, and start with a low max-age, and without includesubdomains and preload - until you truly understand what they mean.
- if running a high risk site, then consider submitting your site to HSTS preload list as a high level of security, but again be aware of risks here. Only do this if you really understand HSTS and feel like you need this level of security.